# Accounting for spatial dependency (pseudoreplication) using lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have different planting containers (known as styroblocks). These containers contain cavities in which seedlings were planted. Cavity volume is constant within a container but varies between containers. Within in each container 15 seedlings were considered for analysis. I want to know whether container has an effect on growth parameters. In order to avoid pseudoreplication, I can either average across these 15 trees and get one value per container, or I can specify the spatial dependence in an lmer model.

5 different container sizes are replicated 3 times with 3 different plant varieties at 2 nurseries (5*3*3*2* 15 trees = 1350 seedlings).

Here's an example dataset:

```
xx <- data.frame(Nursery = rep(c("NursA", "NursB"), each = 675),
             Container= rep(c("ContA", "ContB", "ContC", "ContD", "ContE"), 6, each = 45),
             Variety = rep(c("VarA", "VarB", "VarC"), 2, each  = 225),
             Replicate = rep(c(1,2,3), 30, each = 15), 
             Seedling = rep(1:15,90),
             Height = rnorm(1350, 6))
```

Here's the model I think is most appropriate in this case:

```
require(lme4)
m1<-lmer(Height ~ Nursery+Container+Variety+
Nursery:Container+Nursery:Variety+Container:Variety + (1|Container:Seedling), data=xx)
```

I am not interested in 3-way interaction based on my objectives.

My questions are:

**Q1:** Is this model correctly specified?

**Q2:** Is there are way to figure out from the model output if the correct sample size was used (45 vs. 3 for each nursery, container and clone combination)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own questions which I asked a couple of months ago:

**A1:**

No, it's not correctly specified. Your containers are the experimental unit on which 15 repeated measurements were taken (indicated by your variable `Seedling`). What you need is a container ID:

```
xx$ContainerID <- with(xx, paste(Variety, Container, Replicate, sep="-"))
```

And then:

```
m2 <- lmer(Height ~ Nursery + Container + Variety + Nursery:Container + Nursery:Variety + 
           Container:Variety + (1|Nursery:ContainerID), data = xx)
```

As you can see from the output, you have now correctly specified 90 groups, i.e 45 containers per nursery.

```
summary(m2)

Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Nursery:ContainerID (Intercept) 0.01368  0.117   
 Residual                        1.05179  1.026   
Number of obs: 1350, groups:  Nursery:ContainerID, 90
```

versus 75 groups, which is wrong:

```
summary(m1)

Random effects:
 Groups             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Container:Seedling (Intercept) 0.02176  0.1475  
 Residual                       1.04166  1.0206  
Number of obs: 1350, groups:  Container:Seedling, 75
```

**A2:**

Yes! The total number of observations is 1350 (as can be seen in the outputs above). However, the total number of observations should be (after accounting for the 15 repeated measurements on container):

```
> 2  * 5  * 3  * 3  ## (Nurseries * Containers * Clones * Replicates)
[1] 90
```

This also matches with the number of groups in the `summary(m2)` output above.

Let's have a look at the degrees of freedom. The correct total degrees of freedom are 89 (90-1).

Since there are 6 parameters, with 2, 5, 3, 5, 3 and 9 levels, the total denominator degrees of freedom should be:

```
> 89 - (2-1) - (5-1) - (3-1) - (5-1) - (3-1) - (9-1) 
[1] 68
```

Let's check:

```
>lmerTest::anova(m2)

Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value  Pr(>F)  
Nursery           5.4273  5.4273     1    68  5.0044 0.02856 *
Container         3.1727  0.7932     4    68  0.7314 0.57368  
Variety           0.8197  0.4098     2    68  0.3779 0.68673  
Nursery:Container 0.6144  0.1536     4    68  0.1416 0.96608  
Nursery:Variety   0.5869  0.2935     2    68  0.2706 0.76374  
Container:Variety 2.9298  0.3662     8    68  0.3377 0.94826  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And now your previous model which was obviously wrong:

```
>lmerTest::anova(m1)

Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value   Pr(>F)   
Nursery           7.4686  7.4686     1  1258  6.8252 0.009095 **
Container         3.6609  0.9152     4    70  0.8364 0.506681   
Variety           1.1280  0.5640     2  1258  0.5154 0.597391   
Nursery:Container 0.8455  0.2114     4  1258  0.1932 0.942024   
Nursery:Variety   0.8077  0.4038     2  1258  0.3690 0.691468   
Container:Variety 4.0317  0.5040     8  1258  0.4606 0.884137   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```